# 5.1 channel gain control in Android

Tags: android, audio, hdmi

I'm writing an app to play 5.1 channel audio over HDMI and I'm trying to find a way to control the audio levels of the channels individually.  Right now, the files are encoded in AAC (.m4a) format and I would like the user to be able to set the volume of the front R/L, rear R/L, and Center/LFE separately.  Is there a native way to do this with MediaPlayer?  If not, is there a DSP solution that would allow me to change the channel gains before sending the file to MediaPlayer?

Thanks!